# How to run genymotion personal use run in fullscrean non windowed mode?

Tags: android-emulator, genymotion

I recently downloaded the Genymotion android emulator for windows and **ive been trying to find a way to turn the full-screen mode ''ON''** but unfortunately it still runs windowed. Can anyone please help me figure this out.

If any luck getting it in full-screen mode please let me know how.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

To turn on full screen mode you have to hit the F11 keyboard touch.